# Command Prompt > REG EXPORT > why is this an Invalid syntax?

Tags: command-line, windows-registry, syntax

I'm trying to export the existing settings for .rtf extension with this:

```
REG EXPORT HKCR\.rtf  %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\rtf_fta.reg
```

It says "Invalid syntax".

What is invalid about it?

**UPDATE:**

It worked with the quotes.

**SOLVED!**

REG EXPORT HKCR.rtf  "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\rtf_fta.reg"

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how could I answer my own question? Or maybe I should just delete it completely?

Comment: You need to have 15 rep. Then you can answer as described in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @DavidPostill that you for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have used quotes in the path:

`REG EXPORT HKCR.rtf "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\rtf_fta.reg"`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/670821)

Comment: @CJM could you please explain what additional information you're talking about? And what would be the compete answer to the question? I posted here everything I knew. If you you know the better way to answer the question I asked then post it and I'll accept it as the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ignore my review. On reflection, this answer is fine.